# Tel URI href=“tel:” and vanity numbers?

Tags: html, tel

I was trying to add a vanity number in the href="tel:" link (e.g. tel:"+1800FLOWERS"), but now I am actually not sure if this would work on all devices, or is it more acurate if I just write the numbers out? I mean it would look nicer as vanity.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `tel:` scheme was originally defined in [RFC2806](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2806), which only defined support for digits and some additional characters (see section 2.2).

[RFC3966](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3966), which obsoletes RFC2806, explicitly states that vanity numbers are not supported. From section 5.1.2:

> 5.1.2.  Alphabetic Characters Corresponding to Digits
>
> In some countries, it is common to write phone numbers with
> alphabetic characters corresponding to certain numbers on the
> telephone keypad.  The URI format does not support this notation, as
> the mapping from alphabetic characters to digits is not completely
> uniform internationally, although there are standards [E.161][T1.703]
> addressing this issue.

So you should only use regular numbers in the href attribute. You can still use the vanity number in the text itself, e.g.:

```
<a href="tel:+1-800-356-9377">+1800FLOWERS</a>
```